# DAX Measure - Specific Ranking using RANKX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table that just contains all articles.
Then I have a transactional table that contains a value that I would like to use for the rank. THe same tables has the department information.
The structure is like:

[image]

Now I would like to get the Ranking based in Value, in the end represented in a matrix.

This function shows me the ranking based on the value:

```
RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Article),[Value])
```

If the matrix just contains Article in the rows, then it works.

[image]

But when I add department, then the Rank is calculated for each department.

[image]

How can I get the RANK for each Article regardles of the Department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are creating a measure and that you are putting the results in a "table", rather than a "matrix". If so, then the following DAX works for me.

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Table1), Calculate(Max(Table1[Value])))
```

Note that this is when all of the data comes from a single "Table1". You may need to make updates to the measure above based on your table structure and names.

[image]